# Does Asio's write_some really return immediately?

Tags: c++, asio

According to https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/write_some/overload1.html,

> The function call (write_some) will block until one or more bytes of the data has
> been written successfully, or until an error occurs.

Here's the function:

```
template<
    typename ConstBufferSequence>
std::size_t write_some(
    const ConstBufferSequence & buffers);
```

as we see, a reference to the buffer is passed, which means that the implementation of `write_some` must consume the buffer immediately and entirely. It cannot borrow the buffer for itself to write (to a file descriptor) later.

However, the explanation in the page suggests that it does exactly that: once the first byte is written it can return and continue to write the remaining bytes. How is it possible? The reference to buffer may be destructed after the call.

Comment: Re. `"...once the first byte is written it can return and continue to write the remaining bytes"`, I don't see anything in the link provided that suggests that.  After `write_some` returns no more data will be written.

Comment: @G.M. oh I see, so it writes some ammount of bytes and returns the ammount written so the sender knows if it needs to send more in the next iteration or discard since it wrote everything?

Comment: Yes, that's my understanding.  So, depending on the value returned, several calls may be required before all data is written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`basic_stream_socket::write_some` is equivalent of Berkley socket `send()`( or `write()`) function.

Normally `send()` blocks until all bytes has been sent. But in rare cases, it can be interrupted by `SIGNAL` handler or timeout `SO_SNDTIMEO` at the moment when only part of the data has been transmitted. In this case, `send` returns the number of bytes sent (`one or more bytes`). And one should advance in the buffer and send the remaining bytes later.

Comment: what you mean by send? You mean `write` to a file descriptor? The `write` is blocking as far as I know

Comment: Updated answer.